# How to save a path to json file as raw string

Tags: python, json, escaping

I want to save a path to json file, code as below:

```
def writeToJasonFile(results, filename):
    with open(os.path.join(filename), "w") as fp:
        try:
            fp.write(json.dumps(results))
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception("Exception while writing results " % e)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_path = os.getcwd()
    writeToJasonFile(file_path, 'test.json')
```

When I open json file, the string is saved as escape str: `"C:\\test\\Python Script"`

How could I dump it as raw string? Saying `"C:\test\Python Script"`

Comment: The escape str showin in file is "C:\\test\\Python Script" with double splash

Answer (score 0):

I could do it in another way. I replace '\' with '/' for the path string and then save it. Windows is able to open the location with this format "C:/test/Python Script". If someone has the answer for the original question, please post here.